# React native flatlist sticky headers

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in react native and have some hard tasks to do.

Please see the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18toZsSfRIda9ScHq_rpgXziRaKIriYUt/view) and give me some advices how to achieve animation in first five seconds(photo disappears on scroll)

And the second(keep watching the video) sticky headers. Sticky headers are category names news, business, celebrity and etc. Do you have some ideas?

Is there any plugin to achieve this?

I use flatlist to show data.

Answer (score 3):

This technique can be achieve using [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). See example below

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text> <-- this is where you design the header
  )}
  sections={[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
  ]}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is collasing toolbar in android, you can use library to do this.

Here: https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-collapsing-toolbar

Comment: That's great, thanks! I think this will help me to achieve first animation, Do you have some ideas how to do sticky headers after this?

Comment: Oh i just read this plugin description and it seems it is only for android. I need Android and ios both

Comment: I just sugestion, you can find another and if not, do it by yourself, it's easy.